# Macro not launching on workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I've been using an `sub auto_open` macro on and it's been fine.

However I am now trying to open it from another workbook and the `auto_open` macro doesn't work. It just opens and no macros run.

If I add a `Workbook_open` in "This workbook" to run the same macros it works fine. However if I run the workbook normally (outside of the link) it now opens and doesn't run any macros.

Weirdest thing is if I allow both `auto_open` and `workbook_open` it runs twice which is not what I want obviously.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartMacro
End Sub


Public Sub Auto_Open()
    StartMacro
End Sub
```

My ideal would be to have either as long as it will open when launched normally or via a link in a workbook.

Any ideas why I'm getting these issues?

Answer (score 2):

`auto_open` subs needs to be in a **module**, not in an Excel object (like a sheet's code, nor **ThisWorkbook**).  Here is further reference about [auto-startup options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/auto-macros) in Excel.

Comment: Was the sub location the issue?  If not, there could be at least a couple other culprits...